# Gazebo does not spawn mesh

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to spawn a simple differential drive robot with a mesh for the body, the wheels and the caster ball. The meshes are stores in a folder inside the package called meshes. The name of the package is toycar, so in order to include the meshes, I add the following lines to the definition of the wheel link;

```
<visual>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://toycar/meshes/wheel.stl" scale="1.0 1.0 1.0" />
        </geometry>
</visual>
```

Even if there is no error appearing in the launch of the node, the mesh of the wheel does not appear. This is extended to the other links, but I only worked with this one for now to isolate the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401649/gazebo-does-not-spawn-mesh/) by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2022-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`package://` no longer works. Could you try `${find toycar}/meshes/wheel.stl`. I believe that should work.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on 2022-05-31**:
Thanks, it is working now! In which part of the documentation is this found? In order to be able to check more things in the future

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-31**:
This is a very important point - I've had the same mesh problems before and this was the only way to overcome them. It should be mentioned somewhere in the ROS or Gazebo tutorials.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-31**:
I honestly don't know where in the documentation that's mentioned (if mentioned anywhere). It's one of those things that you pick up over the years I guess?

Could you accept my answer as correct, to mark the question as answered?

**Comment by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on 2022-05-31**:
Sure! I thought I did already. But what is weird is that I just checked the ros tutorials and the gazebo tutorials and cannot find anywhere where they mention that.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-31**:
Could you link to the tutorials where they mention meshes? I've had a quick search and wasn't able to even find a tutorial on meshes.

**Comment by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on 2022-05-31**:
Here: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link
They mention the format I initially put.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-31**:
Ah, yes, wiki.ros consists of ROS1 tutorials, which makes sense since `package://` does work in ROS1. [docs.ros.org](https://docs.ros.org/) will send you to the ROS2 documentation.

**Comment by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on 2022-06-01**:
As you can see in [this link](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/URDF/Building-a-Visual-Robot-Model-with-URDF-from-Scratch.html?highlight=mesh), it is still unchanged in the tutorials. I might try to find it in the git repository and do some pull request.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-01**:
@pablo.arandarod It would be this repository and file: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/blob/humble/source/Tutorials/URDF/Building-a-Visual-Robot-Model-with-URDF-from-Scratch.rst

**Comment by [pablo.arandarod](https://answers.ros.org/users/71974/pablo.arandarod/) on 2022-06-02**:
@ljaniec, just changed it, it was my first pull request

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-03**:
@pablo.arandarod Cool, I hope it won't be the last :)